# Context free grammar for a language

Tags: context-free-grammar

How would I go about writing a context free grammar for the following language:

```
{a^x b^y c^z | x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0, y = x + z}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that

```
b^y = b^(x+z) = b^x b^z
```

So you can rewrite the specification as:

```
a^x b^x b^z c^z
```

Let L = `a^x b^x, x >= 0`, and R = `b^z c^z, z >= 0`

I think you should be able to fill in the rest from there...